# Parking time calculator

Tags: microsoft-excel

In our section, the first 45 minutes are free for parking. After that, small vehicles cost 10 dhs per hour, and big vehicles cost 30 dhs per hour. This means if a driver parks a small vehicle at 8:00am, they can have free parking until 8:45am. After that, it will charge 10 dhs until 9:45am. How can I calculate this in excel?

Note: "dhs" is a way of writing United Arab Emirates Dirhams (AED), which is a type of currency.

Comment: ???? what is a "dhs" as a unit of measurement???

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I have edited your answer with a sidenote, as well as fixing your grammar. I'm assuming you used Google Translate, or at least your first language is definitely not English.

Comment: Well it seems like you have to put something like this into a function `duration = (leave_time-startime-45 minutes); if (duration < 0) totalfee = 0 else totalfee = duration * costperhour`.  What is the current layout of your sheet, how are you entering your times into the sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I have the times in military format for ease of calculating (at least for me), but I made an assumption that you would be starting from the point of knowing the time the car arrived, and also knowing the time of when it left.

[image]

From there, columns A, B, and C are formatted(automatically) as "Custom h:mm"
Column C has the formula: `=B2-A2-"0:45"` to take off the free 45mins
Column D small/large
Column E contains the formula: `=C2*(IF(D2="small", 10, 30))*24` and is formatted as Currency

Some explanation: C2 ends up being hours to bill, but when the time is evaluated for calculations, it is figured on how much of day that time is.  In line 2 below, for instance, 4 hours is 1/6th of a day, or 1 divided by 6, or 0.16667. So the last *24 is to get that back into hours.  The middle part is just giving you 10 if it's a small vehicle, 30 otherwise.  You could nest IF's here to better control entered values if you wanted.